# Warnings ao compilar o programa

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

No código abaixo, eu preciso criar uma estrutura para Ponto (Coordenada x e y) e criar uma função que crie esses pontos, utilizando ponteiros. A estrutura foi feita da seguinte forma:

```
typedef struct //Estrutura definida para os pontos.
{
    double x; //Coordenadas X e Y.
    double y;
} Ponto;
```

Depois criei a função para criar esses pontos e uma outra função para imprimir esses mesmos pontos:

```
void CriaPonto(Ponto *p, double x, double y) //Função que cria n pontos.
{
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    int i, nponto;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de pontos que se quer (Maximo 100): ");
    scanf("%d", &nponto);
    if(nponto < 1 || nponto > 100)
    {
        printf("Quantidade de pontos invalida.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Digite as coordenadas X e Y:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < nponto; i++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", &p[i].x);
            scanf("%lf", &p[i].y);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void ImprimePonto(Ponto P[])
{
    int i, nponto;
    for(i = 0; i < nponto; i++)
            printf("Ponto %d: (%.0lf,%.0lf)\n", i+1, P[i].x, P[i].y);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Na função principal (main) do programa eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
int main()
{
    Ponto Ponto[MAX];

    int x, y;

    CriaPonto(Ponto, x, y);
    ImprimePonto(Ponto);
    return 0;
}
```

Ao compilar eu recebo 3 warnings.

```
In function 'ImprimePonto'
'nponto' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
In function 'main':
'y' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
'x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
```

As dúvidas que tenho são: A maneira com a qual eu criei a função está correta? O que é necessário pra remover esses 3 warnings ao compilar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente no seu `main` você criou as variáveis `x` e `y`, mas não iniciou nenhum valor nelas.

E na função `ImprimePonto` a mesma coisa com a variável `nponto`.

**`main:`**

```
int main(){
    /*...*/
    int x=1,y=3;
    /*...*/
}
```

**`ImprimePonto:`**

```
void ImprimePonto(Ponto P[]){
    /*...*/
    int i, nponto=0;
    /*...*/
}
```

Quando não se inicia um valor nas variáveis, elas podem conter lixo, assim quando são passadas como valores, os resultados não aparecem como o esperado.

Comment: Colocar um valor inicial pra elas, como o 0, não influencia no funcionamento do programa então?

Comment: @Renan, não colocar um valor inicial faz com que possivelmente o programe inicie com valores aleatórios/lixo de memória

Comment: como você está usando valores estáticos, é melhor que você inicie os valores correspondentes aos que você usará